# Date chooser not showing date after conversion

Tags: java, netbeans-7, simpledateformat

After Conversion of date ,the date chooser not displaying date,plz following code. This code giving error.But i tried with setDateFormatString() , but this also not displaying date.

```
String date1 = rs.getString("date");    
java.util.Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date1);
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date2);    
jDateChooser1.setDate(date);
```

Comment: What format is the original `String` value in?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String date = "2014-01-01";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {
    Date formattedDate = formatter.parse(date); 
    System.out.println("" + formattedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```